# Process Wait For Exit not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, process

I'm using the below code to download from youtube using youtube-dl python script.

```
string pythonPath = @"C:\Python35\python.exe";
string ydl = @"C:\Y\ydl\youtube-dl";
string tempLocation = Server.MapPath("/ydl/");

string Output = "";
string Error = "";

int numOutputLines = 0;
int numErrorLines = 0;

using (Process process = new Process())
{
    process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    process.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    process.StartInfo.FileName = pythonPath;
    process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = tempLocation;
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = ydl + " --output test.mp4 --force-ipv4 -f bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a] \"" + Url + "\"";
    process.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder error = new StringBuilder();

    using (AutoResetEvent outputWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false))
    using (AutoResetEvent errorWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false))
    {
        process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Data == null)
            {
                outputWaitHandle.Set();
            }
            else
            {
                numOutputLines++;
                this.Context.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine + "[" + numOutputLines.ToString() + "] - " + e.Data);
                output.AppendLine("[" + numOutputLines.ToString() + "] - " + e.Data);
            }
        };
        process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Data == null)
            {
                errorWaitHandle.Set();
            }
            else
            {
                numErrorLines++;
                this.Context.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine + "[" + numErrorLines.ToString() + "] - " + e.Data);
                error.AppendLine("[" + numErrorLines.ToString() + "] - " + e.Data);
            }
        };

        //process.Exited += (s, a) =>
        //{
        //    process.Close();
        //};

        process.Start();

        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        process.BeginErrorReadLine();

            //process.WaitForExit();
            Process[] curProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("youtube-dl");
            Process youtubeProcess = curProcess.FirstOrDefault();  

            while (!youtubeProcess.HasExited)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }

        Output = output.ToString();
        Error = error.ToString();
        process.Close();
    }
}
```

I used the proccess in this way because I want to have the percentage of youtube-dl script for showing in my client side progress bar.

But there are some problems and it's that `WaitForExit` is not working. I read from other topics that this issue is related to wait in process not working for child process(I mean in my way, the wait for exit works for python not for youtube-dl script)

What should I do?

Comment: What  _exactly_ does "is not working" mean?

Comment: @RenéVogt The process not wait till it end.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are interested in a child process maybe you an try to poll on the youtube process by using the method:

```
Process.GetProcessesByName(string processName);
```

Something like this:

```
   Process[] curProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("your youtube process name");
   Process youtubeProcess = curProcess.FirstOrDefault();  // Get here the right process instance
   while (!youtubeProcess.HasExited)
   {
       Thread.Sleep(100);
   }
```

Comment: I do it as your mention but still not works.I print the `youtubeProcess` value,it's empty.
I edit my code and update the `process.StartInfo.Arguments`.please look at it, and if you know please say what is wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the process name is: 'youtube-dl'? (You should take the name as it appears in the task manager)

Comment: I look at task manager,the processes name related to my process were there **conhost.exe** and **python.exe**.

Comment: Sorry,the value of `youtubeProcess` is not empty.but the condition of loop for `!youtubeProcess.HasExited` condition not works

Comment: Are you sure your process(es) are: conhost.exe and python.exe?

Comment: Yes,as you see in my codes,I used the python path for filename,and  when it runs,conhost.exe and python.exe will be shown in task manager.